# Oracle SubQuery (Display subquery columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I cannot seem to find via searching how I would be able to return some of the columns from the the below sub queries.  Specifically B.TAP_STAT_HSL/C.TAP_STAT_HSL.  I'm not sure if I should be joining instead, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   SELECT 

   A.HSE_KEY_HSE AS HOUSEKEY,
   A.DROP_STAT_HSE AS DROPSTATUS
   A.TAP_STAT_HSL AS ITAPSTAT

   FROM OPS$SEA.HSE_BASE,OPS$SEA.HSL_LOB,OPS$SEA.OOR_ORDER_OPEN A

   WHERE A.HSE_KEY_HSE = A.HSE_KEY_HSL 
   AND A.HSE_KEY_HSL = A.HSE_KEY_OOR
   AND A.DROP_STAT_HSE = '1'
   AND A.LOB_IND_HSL = 'I'
   AND A.TAP_STAT_HSL IN ('0','2')
   AND A.ORD_STAT_OOR <> 'O'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1

   FROM OPS$SEA.HSE_BASE B,OPS$SEA.HSL_LOB B, OPS$SEA.OOR_ORDER_OPEN B

   WHERE A.HSE_KEY_HSE = B.HSE_KEY_HSE
   AND B.HSE_KEY_HSE = B.HSE_KEY_HSL
   AND B.HSE_KEY_HSL = B.HSE_KEY_OOR 
   AND B.DROP_STAT_HSE = '1'
   AND B.LOB_IND_HSL = 'C'
   AND B.TAP_STAT_HSL IN ('0','2')
   AND B.ORD_STAT_OOR <> 'O')
   AND EXISTS (

   SELECT 1

   FROM OPS$SEA.HSE_BASE C,OPS$SEA.HSL_LOB C, OPS$SEA.OOR_ORDER_OPEN C

   WHERE A.HSE_KEY_HSE = C.HSE_KEY_HSE
   AND C.HSE_KEY_HSE = C.HSE_KEY_HSL 
   AND C.HSE_KEY_HSL = C.HSE_KEY_OOR
   AND C.DROP_STAT_HSE = '1'
   AND C.LOB_IND_HSL = 'T'
   AND C.TAP_STAT_HSL IN ('0','2')
   AND C.ORD_STAT_OOR <> 'O')}
```

Comment: can't select from subqueries i'm affraid...

Comment: what should be returned if both `0` and `2` values are present in the tables B and/or C?

Comment: You're asking if you can select anything from your `exists` sub-queries? No, but you can turn them into joins and then you can...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....

I *believe* your query can be re-written as follows:

```
WITH Allowed_Rows (houseKey, dropStatus, ipApStat, indicator) 
                   as (SELECT a.HSE_KEY_HSE, a.DROP_STAT_HSE, 
                              b.TAP_STAT_HSL, b.LOB_IND_HSL
                       FROM OPS$SEA.HSE_BASE as a
                       JOIN OPS$SEA.HSL_LOB as b
                       ON b.HSE_KEY_HSL = a.HSE_KEY_HSE
                       AND b.LOB_IND_HSL IN ('I', 'C', 'T')
                       AND b.TAB_STAT_HSL IN ('0', '2')
                       JOIN OPS$SEA.OOR_Order_Open as c
                       ON c.HSE_KEY_OOR = a.HSE_KEY_HSE
                       AND c.ORD_STAT_OOR <> '0'
                       WHERE a.DROP_STAT_HSE = '1')
SELECT houseKey, dropStatus, ipApStat
FROM Allowed_Rows as a
WHERE a.indicator = 'I'
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1' 
            FROM Allowed_Rows as b
            WHERE b.houseKey = a.houseKey
            AND b.indicator = 'C')
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1'
            FROM Allowed_Rows as b
            WHERE b.houseKey = a.houseKey
            AND b.indicator = 'T')
```

You didn't properly qualify some of your tables, and used the same alias for multiple tables (which I'm surprised didn't generate a syntax error), so I had to make my best guess as to where things actually belong.  There are a couple of other variations possible, depending on the other (unlisted) requirements and constraints.

And why and how do you need to return the 'other' values of `TAP_STAT_HSL`?  DO you need all possible combinations?  The value of the row for `B` or `C` *instead* of `A`?  What?